# Use of as in two different way

Tags: conjunctions

> I am trying to cook the cake as you.
>
> I am trying to cook the cake as yours .

Are both “as” same? I thought both are same but what those modie is different. In the first sentence “as”is used instead of “in the way” I mean my method of cooking is like your method.But in the second sentence it sounds cakes I cook is just like the cakes you cooked. It realy confuses me . Are my thoughts correct ?

Comment: “As you” makes it should like “I am trying to be you when I cook the cake.” “As yours” sounds like you are referring to ownership of the cake.  It should be something like: *I am trying to cook the cake as you have cooked it.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of your sentences is idiomatic.  You need to say

"I am trying to cook the cake as you do",  "...in the way that you do", or "...the same way as you do."

"I am trying to cook a cake like yours." We say that one thing is *like* another, not *as* another.

Comment: Than you so much . I understood very well.